# On/Off switch for Li-ion battery pack

Tags: lithium-ion

Is it ok to tie the battery pack (in my case 3s1p) to a SPST switch to turn it on/off or I should need a series resistor after the switch to limit current and a big fat cap to smooth the on/off transition?

Something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwlRs3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If so how can I calculate the wattage for R1?

This is what the supply is going to power:
[image]

Comment: What kind of load is connected to the battery that requires this kind of "soft start"? What is the purpose of the diode and why this specific diode (with a max current of noy 300mA)?

Comment: This is the power supply to a ~4W AB amp. The diode prevents C1 to discharge to the battery. this is the diode I found in this schematic program. I guess It should be a schottky. But the question remains. Do I need such a circuit or I can just use a switch?

Comment: The LM4952 prevents pops and clicks during turn on and turn off so your resistor and diode are not needed. use a 1000uF battery decoupling capacitor. The volume control you are using has an "A" audio taper but the LM4952 also has an audio taper. Then use a "B" linear taper. The NE5532 is not needed and use 1uF film capacitors feeing the LM4952. The lithium battery cells will be damaged if they discharge less than 3V each, add a voltage monitor/disconnect circuit.

Comment: @Audioguru:  ok UVLO circuit, ok 1000uF decoupling capacitor. Not sure what do you mean that the LM4952 has an audio taper. Also I think it is a good idea to use a voltage follower at the input to provide a low impedance output to the LM input

Answer (score 1):

What you need is precharge: two switches, one through a resistor and one directly. First you turn the switch through the resistor, then, 1 second or so later, you turn on the direct switch.

I wrote a white paper on that: http://liionbms.com/php/precharge.php

Another approach is to use an ICL ([inrush current limiter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inrush_current_limiter)) in series.

Answer (score 0):

Your volume control has an audio taper so that when turned to 50% the volume is reduced a fair amount. But the LM4952 also has a non-linear taper then adding them makes the volume control wrong, turning down the volume control to 50% causes the sound to be very very low volume.

[image: volume control]